# connect ETIMEDOUT 2404:6800:4002:82c::200a:443",

Tags: youtube-api

Whenever I am making an API call to Google YouTube API it shows me this error:

> connect ETIMEDOUT 2404:6800:4002:82c::200a:443"

Most of the time, it works properly but suddenly it shows this error unexpectedly.

I checked my code it same as when it work properly.